# Am I changing pages with JavaScript correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My `index.html` page contains 4 separate elements with the class "Content", and are defaulted with `display:hidden` until told otherwise by an onclick event handler, the below function.

So, basically my setup entails 4 webpages in one, each one hidden until told to load.

Is this a proper method for implementing page changes?

```
// Page Change Function

function ChangeContent(page) {
    var pgHome = document.getElementById("homepage");
    var pg1 = document.getElementById("page1");
    var pg2 = document.getElementById("page2");
    var pg3 = document.getElementById("page3");

switch (page) {

// Load Homepage element
    case "Home":    pgHome.style.display = 'block';
                    pg1.style.display = 'none';
                    pg2.style.display = 'none';
                    pg3.style.display = 'none';
                    location.hash = "Home";
                    document.title = "Home";
                    break;

// Load Page1 element
    case "Page1":   pgHome.style.display = 'none';  
                    pg1.style.display = 'block';
                    pg2.style.display = 'none';
                    pg3.style.display = 'none';
                    location.hash = "Page 1";
                    document.title = "Page 1";
                    break;

// Load Page2 element
     case "Page2":  pgHome.style.display = 'none';    
                    pg1.style.display = 'none';
                    pg2.style.display = 'block';
                    pg3.style.display = 'none';
                    location.hash = "Page 2";
                    document.title = "Page 2";
                    break;

// Load Page3 element
    case "Page3":   pgHome.style.display = 'none';    
                    pg1.style.display = 'none';
                    pg2.style.display = 'none';
                    pg3.style.display = 'block';
                    location.hash = "Page 3";
                    document.title = "Page 3";
                    break;

    }
}
```

Comment: You could avoid a lot of code duplication by implementing a `hideAll()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you have used makes your code redundant.

A quicker and cleaner way is to hide unneeded pages, and show the page that is needed.

```
function ChangeContent(page) {
    var pages={"homepage":{title: "Home"}, "page1":{title: "Page 1"}, "page2":{title: "Page 2"},"page3":{title: "Page 3"}};


    //Show the only one needed
    for(var pageName in pages)
    {
        if(page!==pageName)
        {
            document.getElementById(pageName).style.display='none';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(pageName).style.display='block';
            location.hash=pages[pageName].title;
            document.title=pages[pageName].title;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note: In the original code the names that the function is called with is not the same as the identities of the elements. This code assumes that they are. (Also, the code doesn't actually hide the unneeded pages first and then show the page that is needed.)

Comment: @Guffa I've changed the "first" and "then" words from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that works. You could however put the information for the pages in an array, that makes the code less repetetive, and it's a lot easier to add pages when needed:

```
var pages = [
  { name: 'Home', id: 'homepage', hash: 'Home', title: 'Home' },
  { name: 'Page1', id: 'page1', hash: 'Page 1', title: 'Page 1' },
  { name: 'Page2', id: 'page2', hash: 'Page 2', title: 'Page 2' },
  { name: 'Page3', id: 'page3', hash: 'Page 3', title: 'Page 3' }
];

function ChangeContent(page) {
  for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    var current = pages[i].name == page;
    document.getElementById(pages[i].id).style.display = current ? 'block' : 'none';
    if (current) {
      location.hash = pages[i].hash;
      document.title = pages[i].title;
    }
  }
}
```